# Discord py permission system (cant kick self, cant kick mods)

Tags: python, discord, bots

I'm writing a kick command, which has turned out successfully. Today i found out that half my admins banned themselves for fun, so with that problem i wanted a line or two where if a moderator attempts kicking/banning themselves or someone with lets say the `manage_guild` permissions the bot would return something like "That user is a staff member. I cannot kick them!"
Extra points if i got something for other bots where it says "The member you're trying to kick is a bot!" perhaps through a "Bot" role.

Here's the code -

```py
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def kick(ctx, user: discord.Member, *, reason="No reason provided"):
        await user.kick(reason=reason)
        kick = discord.Embed(title=f"User {user.name}#{user.discriminator} has been **kicked** from the server. <a:m_verifyblack:850825891780100096>", color=0xFF8300, description=f"Reason: {reason}\nBy: {ctx.author.mention}")
        await ctx.message.delete()
        await ctx.channel.send(embed=kick)
@kick.error
async def kick_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):
        await ctx.send("**:no_entry_sign: You cant do that!**")
@kick.error
async def kick_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
        kick = discord.Embed(title=f"Please pass a user.", description="`.kick {user}`\nExample:\n`.kick @user`,   `.kick {user.id}`")
        await ctx.channel.send(embed=kick)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply check if the target `user` has the `kick_members` permission and react accordingly.
You can also check if `user` is a `bot` actually.

Here's a modified version of your code that does the trick:

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def kick(ctx, user: discord.Member, *, reason="No reason provided"):
        if not user.permissions_in(ctx.channel).kick_members or user.bot:
                return await ctx.send("You cannot kick staff members or bots")

        await user.kick(reason=reason)
        kick = discord.Embed(title=f"User {user.name}#{user.discriminator} has been **kicked** from the server. <a:m_verifyblack:850825891780100096>", color=0xFF8300, description=f"Reason: {reason}\nBy: {ctx.author.mention}")
        await ctx.message.delete()
        await ctx.channel.send(embed=kick)
@kick.error
async def kick_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):
        await ctx.send("**:no_entry_sign: You cant do that!**")
@kick.error
async def kick_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
        kick = discord.Embed(title=f"Please pass a user.", description="`.kick {user}`\nExample:\n`.kick @user`,   `.kick {user.id}`")
        await ctx.channel.send(embed=kick)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try checking the mentioned person's permissions. For example, if I didn't want the bot to kick a person with `ban_members` permissions:

```
if user.guild_permissions.ban_members:
    await ctx.channel.send("Cannot kick this person.")
```

Also, to prevent from kicking yourself, you can try:

```
if ctx.message.author == user:
    await ctx.channel.send("You can't kick yourself.")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's your command with the wanted changes!

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def kick(ctx, user: discord.Member, *, reason="Reason not provided"):
        #
        #start of the code i added
        if ctx.message.author == user: #checks if user is the author of the message
            await ctx.send("You can't kick yourself!") #sends a warning
            return 0 #skips the command, preventing the self kick
        if user == user.bot: #checks if targeted user is a bot
            await ctx.send("You cannot kick a bot!") #sends a warning
            return 0 #skips the command, preventing bot kick
        #end of the code i added
        #
        await user.kick(reason=reason)
        kick = discord.Embed(title=f"User {user.name}#{user.discriminator} has been **kicked** from the server. <a:m_verifyblack:850825891780100096>", color=0xFF8300, description=f"Reason: {reason}\nBy: {ctx.author.mention}")
        await ctx.message.delete()
        await ctx.channel.send(embed=kick)
@kick.error
async def kick_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):
        await ctx.send("**:no_entry_sign: You cant do that!**")
@kick.error
async def kick_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
        kick = discord.Embed(title=f"Please pass a user.", description="`.kick {user}`\nExample:\n`.kick @user`,   `.kick {user.id}`")
        await ctx.channel.send(embed=kick)
```

Here, `return 0` make the rest of the command skip, so that, it will prevent the kick. With the code I added, you cannot kick yourself and you can't kick any bot in the server.